# Take the derivative w.r.t. a vector $v$ and solve for $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-calculus

How do you solve for the vector $v$?

- $v$ = $p \times 1$
- $x_i$ = $p \times 1$ constant
- $c_i$ = scalar constant
- $d$ vector of constants

$0 = \frac{d}{dv} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i (x_i^{T} v) (v^{T}x_i) \right] + d$

What I have right now, but I am not sure it is correct:

$0 = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v x_i^{T} x_i + d$

$v = \frac{d}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i^{T} x_i} $

Answer (score 2):

The objective function is
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\Si{\sum_{i=1}^n}
\phi &= \LR{\Si c_ix_ix_i^T}:vv^T \;=\; XCX^T:vv^T \\
}$$
where
$$\eqalign{
&C = \Diag{c_i}, \qquad X &= \m{x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n}, \quad A:B = \trace{A^TB} \\
}$$
Its gradient is
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= XCX^T:\LR{v\:dv^T+dv\:v^T} \;=\; 2XCX^Tv:dv \\
\grad{\phi}{v} &= 2XCX^Tv \\
}$$
Equating this to the given vector yields
$$
v = -\LR{\frac12}\left(XCX^T\right)^{-1}d \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 
$$